# Boolean Algebra: Simplify AB + A'C + B'C

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

I can't use K-maps. I've managed to bring it down to C + ABC', not sure if I did it right and I think I can simplify further, but don't know how to. I also feel like there's a simpler method I'm missing.

AB + A'C + B'C
= AB + A'BC + A'B'C + B'C
= AB + A'BC + B'C (1 + A')
= AB + A'BC + B'C
= ABC + ABC' + A'BC + B'C
= BC(A+A') + ABC' + B'C
= BC + B'C + ABC'
= C + ABC'

I have a second question, might as well add it here because it's also simplification of boolean algebra.

f = cx + ac'x + bc'x + a'b'c'x' (used a K-map to generate this, now I have to simplify further)
f = c'x(a+b) + cx + a'b'c'x' - no idea how to continue from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AB+A'C+B'C $

$=AB+C(A'+B')$

$=AB + C(AB)'$

$=AB+C$

Comment: I would remove the word hint, sorry!!

Comment: No harm done, feel reassured.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought. I got to that second line on my first try but got stuck there, I forgot about De Morgan's Laws. Thanks for the help. Could you please help with my other question (edited into my main post) if possible?

Comment: Use the logic that I have used in step 3 of the first problem into your first two terms of the second problem.  The last term cannot be reduced any further

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{aligned}AB+A'C+B'C & =AB\left(C'+C\right)+A'\left(B+B'\right)C+\left(A+A'\right)B'C\\
 & =ABC'+ABC+A'BC+A'B'C+AB'C+A'B'C\\
 & =ABC'+ABC+A'BC+A'B'C+AB'C\\
 & =ABC'+ABC+ABC+A'BC+A'B'C+AB'C\\
 & =AB\left(C'+C\right)+\left(AB+A'B+A'B'+AB'\right)C\\
 & =AB+\left(A+A'\right)\left(B+B'\right)C\\
 & =AB+C
\end{aligned}
$

Constructive advice:

Make a Venn-diagram and observe that: $$(A\cap B)\cup(A^{\complement}\cap C)\cup(B^{\complement}\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cup C$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. That Venn diagram is pretty useful advice for checking the answer. Could you please help with the other question (edited into my main post) if possible?

Comment: $c+ac'+bc'=c+a+b$ leading to $\cdots=(a+b+c)x+a'b'c'x'=(a+b+c)x+(a+b+c)'x'$